# Como exibir para o admin os dados específicos de cada usuário escolhido com rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Na parte administrativa que estou fazendo meu Admin consegue visualizar todas as Subscriptions realizadas por usuários em uma tabela (essa parte está funcionando perfeitamente)

Código do meu admin controller,

```
def index
  @subs = Subscription.all
end
```

Código de exibição da tabela

```
table.table#table-admin
  thead
    tr
      th CPF
      th Cód
      th Endereço
      th Data
      th Tipo
      th Status
      th Do
  tbody
    - @subs.each do |subs|
      tr
        td = subs.user.cpf
        td = subs.realty.realty_code
        td = subs.realty.address.street + " , " + subs.realty.address.number
        td = subs.created_at.strftime("%d %b, %Y")
        td = subs.realty.listings.first.translated_listing_type
        td = subs.translated_status
        td
          button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#info" X
```

Imagem da tabela
[image: Tabela de lista de inscrições]

Ao clicar no botão X ele chama um modal que deve exibir as informações do  usuário que ela escolheu da tabela, porém não sei como passar especificamente o de cada um.

Comment: Os dados que vc quer exibir no modal, estão todos na tela ou você precisa buscar do banco?

Comment: No modal ta exibindo só um html qualquer pra fazer o front-end. Alguns dos dados são esses da tabela, mas vou precisar buscar outros no banco

Comment: Tem vários modos de resolver, mas nao sei se o stack overflow vai deixar isso ficar aqui, acho melhor vc perguntar lá na rails-br do google groups.

Answer (score 1):

Faria via uma requisição Ajax do Rails nativo (Unobtrusive JavaScript). 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Primeiro você tem que definir o que esse modal irá mostrar, crie no seu routes.rb uma chamada para sua action customizada

#### route.rb

```
resources :subscription do
  get 'modal', on: :member
end
```

#### na view

```
tr
  td= link_to modal_subscription_path(subs), :class => 'btn btn-info', :title => t('show', :scope => 'helpers.links'), remote:true do
```

#### subscription_controller.rb

```
respond_to :html, :js

def modal
  respond_with Subscription.find(params[:id])
end
```

você deve criar um arquivo

#### app/views/subscription/modal.js.erb

```
$('#responsive-modal .modal-content').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'modal') %>");
$('#responsive-modal').modal('show');
```

crie um arquivo

#### app/views/subscription/_modal.html.slim

```
#Aqui coloque o html que você quer que apareça no modal
```

adiciona no teu

#### app/layouts/application.html.slim

```
#modal
  #responsive-modal.modal.fade aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" style=("display: none;") tabindex="-1" 
   .modal-dialog
     .modal-content
```